# PHP in array not working

Tags: php, arrays, function

Here is my code

```
$arr = array('id', 'string');
    // check keys do not contain id or string
    if(in_array($arr, $keys) == true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var_dump($keys);
        var_dump($arr);
    }
            return true;
```

The repsonse from the function;

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'mohooho' (length=14)
  1 => string 'string' (length=6)
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'id' (length=2)
  1 => string 'string' (length=6)
boolean true
```

Am I going mad? Or am I that tired? What the hell is going on here?

**EDIT**

Ok on my machine I have this and I can swear I on my mother's life, I am using wamp php 5.4

```
// check keys do not contain id or string
    if(in_array(array('string', 'id'), array('string', 'id'))) {
        echo 'IN ARRAY';
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
```

http://writecodeonline.com/php/ <<<<**TEST THE CODE HERE**

I get `ERROR!`,

But this works,

```
// check keys do not contain id or string
    if(in_array('string', array('string', 'id'))) {
        echo 'IN ARRAY';
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
```

I now get the proper response `IN_ARRAY`

Any thoughts?

Comment: what is the value of `$keys`?

Comment: You can see it at the bottom, $keys is the first var_dump, and $arr is the second, loving the down votes some people are so cruel on here!

Comment: Why does `string 'mohooho'` have a length of 14? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Am also totally confused with your question.. I'm asking whats the value `$keys` hold?

Comment: @DCoder : It will comes from `else` part with `var_dump` of `array`.

Comment: @Ranjith: there's a `var_dump($keys)` inside the script...

Comment: @DCoder : then what he checks in `if loop`. without assigned any value for `$keys`

Comment: @DCoder & @Ranjith Please test the code in your php environment `in_array(array('string', 'id'), array('string', 'id'))` returns false!

Comment: You're misunderstanding how `in_array` works. It looks for a single `needle` element. `array('string', 'id')` does *not* contain an element `array('string', 'id')`, therefore you get `false`. If you want to make sure that all given keys exist in an array, use `array_diff_key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I can think of why this returns `ERROR`:

```
if (in_array(array('string', 'id'), array('string', 'id')))
{
    echo 'IN ARRAY';
}
else
{
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

is because PHP is checking each of the haystack's values against the needle itself. Suppose you have 2 arrays like so:

```
$a = array('string', 'id');
$b = array('string', 'id');
```

`$a` and `$b` are the same right? If you feed these to `in_array`, `$a` being the needle and `$b` being the haystack, it checks is `$b[0]` equal to `$a`? False. But if you make the arrays like this and do `in_array($a, $b)`:

```
$a = array('string', 'id');
$b = array(array('string', 'id'), 'id');
```

it will return true because `$b[0]` is equal to `$a` itself or wherever `$a` occurred within the haystack which is `$b`.